# C++ Xcode template function and array <int, i> as function variabel

Tags: c++, xcode, template-function

Folks,

trying to figure out why Xcode 6.0 doesn't like this syntax

```
template <int i>
int test(array<int, i> v) 
{
  int result = 0;
  for (int value : v) {
     result += value;
  }    
 return result; 
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
    array<int, 5> n = { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } };
    cout << test(n);
    return 0;
}
```

I see Xcode complains about no matching function for test(n) call.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because the type of the second template parameter to `std::array` is `std::size_t`, not `int`. Change the declaration to:

```
template <size_t i>
int test(array<int, i> v)
```